# Timepicker Dialog and SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I created a `TextView` which opens up a `TimePickerDialog` and I am able to select time, it updates the `TextView` correctly with the time chosen. But whenever I leave the `Activity` and come back, the `TextView` updates to the current time, however what I want is to save the selected time to `SharedPreferences` and change it only when I decide to change. I've spent 2 days on this but I couldn't get the time saved. Please help, following is my code.

```
package com.example.dexter.ddiary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class RemindersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();


    TextView mTimeView;


    private int pHour;
    private int pMinute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;


    private void updateDisplay() {
        mTimeView.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(pHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(pMinute)));


    }


    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);


        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = RemindersActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isMyValueChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox", false);
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_alert);
        checkbox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        findViewById(R.id.checkbox_alert).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("checkbox", ((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
                editor.commit();


                calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, pHour);
                calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, pMinute);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReciever.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(),
                        alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);


            }
        });

        mTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_set);
        mTimeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        pHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


    }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(RemindersActivity.this, mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute, false);

        }

        return null;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    pHour = hourOfDay;
                    pMinute = minute;

                    updateDisplay();      
                }
            };      
}
```

Comment: is it that it wont save, and you getting a blank value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to do 2 things in your code.

First, you need to save the data when user set time, then, you need to load the data from `SharedPreferences` when `Activity` is created.

To do the first, you'll get your time string and will save it to `SharedPreferences`. I've changed your code (didn't test) to clarify:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    String timeSet = new StringBuilder()
            .append(pad(pHour)).append(":")
            .append(pad(pMinute)).toString();

    mTimeView.setText(timeSet);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = RemindersActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
    sharedPref.putString("timeSet", timeSet);
    sharedPref.commit();
}
```

Now you're saving time everytime user change in the `TimePickerDialog`.

Now, in `onCreate()`, you'll load to the `TextView`:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = RemindersActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isMyValueChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox", false);
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_alert);
checkbox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);
mTimeView.setText(sharedPref.getString("timeSet", null));
```

So, everytime your `Activity` is created, it will get the data from `sharedPreferences`, and when changed, will change there too.

Hope it helps

Comment: You've missed what to assign to sharedPref in the latter code block, also please put the code you've tested and sure about!

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with Identation. =D

Comment: Thank you so much this one worked though i had to move mTimeView.setText(sharedPref.getString("timeSet", null));   // To
        });

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        pHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE); mTimeView.setText(sharedPref.getString("timeSet", null)) // Here


    }

Answer (score 0):

> what i want is to save the selected time to `SharedPreferences`

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox", ((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
            editor.commit();
```

You haven't saved your time to `SharedPreferences`. You've only saved whether or not the `CheckBox` is checked.

When you update `pHour` and `pMinute`, your values are saved until you close the app. If you want them to be saved after that, put them in `SharedPreferences` like you did with the `boolean` above. Then to set the values here:

```
    private void updateDisplay() {
    mTimeView.setText(new StringBuilder()
            .append(pad(pHour)).append(":") //use values from SharedPreferences here instead of pHour
            .append(pad(pMinute))); //and here instead of pMinute


}
```

get the values from `SharedPreferences` instead of just using the class variables. If you do that, does it work?